# Question about CLI и package.json nest.js

Tags: nestjs, консоль, package.json

Question about CLI и package.json nest.js
Typeorm migration needs to pass filename via CLI package.json:

```
 "typeorm:generate-migration": "npm run typeorm -- -d ./typeorm-migration.config.ts migration:generate ./migrations/$npm_config_name",
```

Call:

```
 npm run typeorm:generate-migration --name=CreatePost
```

The name is not taken from the query string, but prints '$npm_config_name'.
$npm_config_name doesn't seem to work with npm 7. In Windows it works if you use %npm_config_name%
I searched for a long time and did not find a cross-platform version of a simple

Comment: переведите пожалуйста вопрос на русский язык, или задайте его на соответствующей языковой версии ресурса

Comment: на Stack Overflow на русском вопросы принято задавать **только на русском языке**. Пожалуйста, переведите ваш вопрос на русский язык или воспользуйтесь Stack Overflow на английском.